# Electric field of a spherical shell

Tags: physics

I hope this question is appropriate for this site, if not, just leave a comment and I will delete.

I am interested in knowing how to derive the electric field due to a spherical shell by Coulomb's law without using **double** integrals or Gauss Law.

Relevant equations are -- Coulomb's law for electric field and the volume of a sphere:

> $\vec{E} = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{Q}{r^2}\hat{r}$, where $Q =$
>   charge, $r=$ distance.
>
> $V = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3.$

From my book, I know that the spherical shell can be considered as a collection of rings piled one above the other but with each pile of rings the radius gets smaller and smaller.

I am not interested in the final formula, just the derivation of it. Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with integrals?

Comment: @nbubis we can use integrals, just not double integrals.

Comment: you realize that in essence you will integrate over all rings, but each ring will also contain an integral. You can call this two single integrals, but really it's a double integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can first calculate the field of a ring centered at $z=z_0$ on the $z$ axis with radius $r$ (using CGS, multiply by ugly factors later). By symmetry, on the $z$ axis the field is only in the $z$ direction and can be shown to be:
$$E_z(z)=\frac{q(z-z_0)}{((z-z_0)^2+r^2)^{3/2}}$$
Now each ring has charge $q=Q\cos \theta d\theta$, and $z_0 = R\cos \theta$. This means you can integrate the expression $E_z(z)$ over $\theta$ to get the field at any point on the $z$ axis. By symmetry, you can choose the ring direction as you wish, so that this expression is true for points not on the $z$ axis as well, with $r$ replacing $z$.

As I mentioned in the comments, since the field of each ring contains an integral, this is really a double integral, even if you decide to call this "two single integrals".

Comment: Why will it have charge $q=Q\cos \theta d\theta$ and $z_0 = R\cos \theta$? And how did you get that $(z-z_0)$? Thanks

Comment: Please can you check my computation ? I find $$q= \frac Q {2} \sin \theta \, d \theta$$$$E_z(z)=\frac{q(z-z_0)}{((z-z_0)^2+(r \sin \theta)^2)^{3/2}}$$.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo - perhaps you are correct, I'll check this later.

Answer (score 3):

We assume that the sphere of radius $R$ centered at 0. Let us assume an observation
point $o$ above the north pole of the sphere (by symmetry this should provide a
good answer). We consider rings from the bottom up to the north polo $(0,0,R)$.
The ring at a high $z$, $-R \le z \le R$ has a radius
$\rho=\sqrt{R^2 - z^2}$. We prefer to see the problem as a function
of the polar angle from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$. We have that $\rho=R \sin \theta$ with $\theta$
the polar angle.  It is well known that for a ring with uniform charge density
$\sigma$ , radius $r$ and an observation point in the axis of the ring at a
distance $d$ from the center (in the direction of the axis of the ring) produces the field

\begin{eqnarray*}
  E(d,\rho)= \frac{\sigma  \rho \, d}{2 \epsilon_0(\rho^2 + d^2)^{3/2}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
The distance between the observation point $o$ and the ring at  $z$
height is $d=o-z$, and $z=R \cos \theta$, then we find

\begin{eqnarray*}
  E(\theta)= 
  \frac{\sigma (o-R \cos \theta) 
    R \sin \theta}{2 \epsilon_0(R^2 \sin^2 \theta + (o-R \cos \theta)^2)^{3/2}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
We need to integrate along $\theta$ between $0$ and $\pi$.
Along the polar axis the element of integration is $d \ell = R \, d \theta$,
so we will need to multiply by $R \, d \theta$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
  E = \frac{\sigma}{2 \epsilon_0} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} 
  \frac{(o-R \cos \theta) 
    R^2 \sin \theta}{(R^2 \sin^2 \theta + (o-R \cos \theta)^2)^{3/2}}
    d \theta.
\end{eqnarray*}
Let us perform the following substitution

\begin{eqnarray*}
  u= \cos \theta \quad , \quad du=- \sin \theta d \theta \\
  \theta=0 \implies u = 1\\
  \theta=\pi \implies u = -1 , 
\end{eqnarray*}
then

\begin{eqnarray*}
  E = \frac{\sigma R^2}{2 \epsilon_0} \int_{-1}^1
  \frac{o - u R}{(R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u)^{3/2}} du
\end{eqnarray*}
We split the integrand in two fractions (forget the coefficient for now).

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int_{-1}^1 \frac{o} {(R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u)^{3/2}} du
  \quad  \mathrm{and} \quad
  -\int_{-1}^1 \frac{u R} {(R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u)^{3/2}} du
\end{eqnarray*}
For the first integral, let us make $x=R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u$,
then $dx=-2 o R du$, and  in terms of $x$,

\begin{eqnarray*}
  -\frac{1}{2 R} \int \frac{dx}{x^{3/2}} =  
  \frac{1}{ R \sqrt{x} },
\end{eqnarray*}
Then the first integral is

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int_{-1}^1 \frac{o} {(R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u)^{3/2}} du &=&
  \left . \frac{1}{R \sqrt{R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u}} \right |_0^1 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Let us do the second integral usig integration by parts.
We write

\begin{eqnarray*}
  -\int_{-1}^1 \frac{u R} {(R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u)^{3/2}} du &=&
    -\frac{u }{o  \sqrt{R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u}} \\
    && + \int
  \frac{1}{o  \sqrt{R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u}} du 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{1}{o  \sqrt{R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u}} du =
-\frac{1}{o^2 R} \sqrt{R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u},
\end{eqnarray*}
then

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int_{-1}^1 \frac{u R} {(R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u)^{3/2}} du &=&
    \frac{u }{o  \sqrt{R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u}} 
    + \frac{ \sqrt{R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u}}{o^2 R} \\
    &=& \frac{ R^2 + o^2 -  o R u}{o^2 R \sqrt{R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u}}
\end{eqnarray*}
Putting the first and the second integrals back together we get

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \frac{1}{R \sqrt{R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u}} 
  - \frac{ R^2 + o^2 -  o R u}{o^2 R \sqrt{R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u}}
  =
  \frac{-R^2 + o Ru}{o^2 R \sqrt{R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u}}
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence we found that

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int \frac{o - u R}{(R^2 + o^2 - 2 o R u)^{3/2}} du
  = \frac{o u - R}{o^2  \sqrt{o^2 - 2 o R u + R^2}},
\end{eqnarray*}
and so

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \left .
  \frac{o u - R}{o^2  \sqrt{o^2 - 2 o R u + R^2}} \right |_{-1}^1
  &=&  \frac{o  - R}{o^2  \sqrt{o^2 - 2 o R  + R^2}} 
  + \frac{o + R}{o^2  \sqrt{o^2 + 2 o R  + R^2}} \\
  &=&
  \frac{o  - R}{o^2  |o - R|}
  + \frac{o + R}{o^2 |o + R|}
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
E= \frac{\sigma R^2}{2 \epsilon_0} 
\left [
  \frac{o  - R}{o^2  |o - R|}
  + \frac{o + R}{o^2 |o + R|}
\right ].
\end{eqnarray*}
That is

\begin{eqnarray*}
E = \left \{
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \frac{\sigma R^2}{o^2 \epsilon_0} &  o > R \\
    \\
      0 &  o < R 
\end{array}
  \right .
\end{eqnarray*}
but

\begin{eqnarray*}
    \frac{\sigma R^2}{o^2 \epsilon_0} 
    = \frac{4 \pi \sigma R^2}{4 \pi o^2 \epsilon_0} 
    = \frac{Q}{4 \pi o^2 \epsilon_0} 
\end{eqnarray*}
where $4 \pi R^2 \sigma$ is the total charge in the sphere.
Then

\begin{eqnarray*}
E = \left \{
  \begin{array}{cc}
  \frac{Q}{4 \pi o^2 \epsilon_0} &  o > R \\
    \\
      0 &  o < R 
\end{array}
  \right .
\end{eqnarray*}

What if $o=R$?

Comment: in your third equation from the top, you have four sine terms but two of them should be cosine (specifically, the ones subtracted from $o$)

Comment: @chrysaor4 : Thanks, I corrected that.

Answer (score 2):

You can derive the electric field without using double integrals explicitely, using Gauss law:

$$ \Phi = \epsilon_0 Q $$

Where $\Phi$ is the flow of the electric field across the Gaussian surface. By symmetry you can choose a sphere of radius $R$ bigger than the radius of the charged sphere and the field will be normal and constant on all the surface, so $\Phi = 4\pi R^2 E$, from here you find

$${\bf E} = \frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2} \hat{\bf r} $$

If one insists in dividing the shpere in rings I see no way to avoid integration.

Comment: Ah, I am sorry I didn't mention that I couldn't use gauss law either. Sorry about that, I knew I was missing something.